# How can i access sub elements in JSON doc

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

Here is my problem, i am trying to parse a object which has multiple objects but they are not in form of Objects in array. My data looks like this

```
{ "Jurisdiction": {
         "Mwd Water Stdby Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$10"
        },
         "Mosq/Fire Ant Assmt": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$7"
        },
         "Vector Control Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$2"
        },
         "Total Of Special Assessments": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$19"
        }
    }
```

and i actually am trying to convert this to an Array of obj like

```
{ "Jurisdiction":[{
         "Tax Name" : "Mwd Water Stdby Chg",
         "Tax Type": "Actual",
          "Tax Amount": "$10"
        }...]
```

i tried multiple ways to access the Tax Type etc under the elements with no luck.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj.Jurisdiction);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {


  console.log(keys[i]["Tax Type"])
  console.log([keys[i]]["Tax Type"])
}
```

all return undefined

Comment: since `keys` are keys of `obj.Jurisdiction`, then it's obvious you need to use `obj.Jurisdiction[keys[i]]`

Comment: you may need to use nested `Object.keys().forEach` and push element for an areay. You can also take a look into the .toArray method from lodash's lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entires()` and `map()`

```js
const obj = { "Jurisdiction": {
         "Mwd Water Stdby Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$10"
        },
         "Mosq/Fire Ant Assmt": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$7"
        },
         "Vector Control Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$2"
        },
         "Total Of Special Assessments": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$19"
        }
    }
}

let res = Object.entries(obj.Jurisdiction).map(x => ({'Tax Name':x[0],...x[1]}));
obj.Jurisdiction = res;

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with `Object.entries`:

```js
const obj = {
  "Jurisdiction": {
    "Mwd Water Stdby Chg": {
      "Tax Type": "Actual",
      "Tax Amount": "$10"
    },
    "Mosq/Fire Ant Assmt": {
      "Tax Type": "Actual",
      "Tax Amount": "$7"
    },
    "Vector Control Chg": {
      "Tax Type": "Actual",
      "Tax Amount": "$2"
    },
    "Total Of Special Assessments": {
      "Tax Type": "Actual",
      "Tax Amount": "$19"
    }
  }
};

obj.Jurisdiction = Object.entries(obj.Jurisdiction).map(([k, v]) => ({ "Tax Name": k, ...v }));

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for in loop instead:

```js
var obj = { "Jurisdiction": {
         "Mwd Water Stdby Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$10"
        },
         "Mosq/Fire Ant Assmt": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$7"
        },
         "Vector Control Chg": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$2"
        },
         "Total Of Special Assessments": {
             "Tax Type": "Actual",
             "Tax Amount": "$19"
        }
      }
  }
var jur = obj.Jurisdiction, j;
for(var i in jur){
   j = jur[i];
   console.log(i);
   console.log(j['Tax Type']);
   console.log(j['Tax Amount']);
   console.log('-----------------------------');
}
```